# How to add Datepicker dialog fragment to Preferences

Tags: java, android

I have an android project with Time Picker Dialog and i wish to add the DATE PICKER to the preferences

I'v tried several codes , but none of them worked for me

#### pref_dialog_time.xml

```
<!-- Layout for the TimePreference Dialog -->
<TimePicker
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="18dp"
    android:paddingTop="18dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppAlertDialogContent"/>
```

#### TimePreference.java

```
public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference {

    private int mTime;
    private int mDialogLayoutResId = R.layout.pref_dialog_time;

    public TimePreference(Context context) {
        // Delegate to other constructor
        this(context, null);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        // Delegate to other constructor
        // Use the preferenceStyle as the default style
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.preferenceStyle);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        // Delegate to other constructor
        this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
    public int getTime() {
        return mTime;
    }
    public void setTime(int time) {
        mTime = time;

        // Save to SharedPreference
        persistInt(time);
    }
    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        // The type of this preference is Int, so we read the default value from the attributes
        // as Int. Fallback value is set to 0.
        return a.getInt(index, 0);
    }
    @Override
    public int getDialogLayoutResource() {
        return mDialogLayoutResId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue, Object defaultValue) {
        // If the value can be restored, do it. If not, use the default value.
        setTime(restorePersistedValue ?
                getPersistedInt(mTime) : (int) defaultValue);
    }

}
```

#### TimePreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java

```
public class TimePreferenceDialogFragmentCompat extends PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat {

    private TimePicker mTimePicker;
    public static TimePreferenceDialogFragmentCompat newInstance(String key) {
        final TimePreferenceDialogFragmentCompat
                fragment = new TimePreferenceDialogFragmentCompat();
        final Bundle b = new Bundle(1);
        b.putString(ARG_KEY, key);
        fragment.setArguments(b);

        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
        super.onBindDialogView(view);

        mTimePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.edit);

        // Exception: There is no TimePicker with the id 'edit' in the dialog.
        if (mTimePicker == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Dialog view must contain a TimePicker with id 'edit'");
        }

        // Get the time from the related Preference
        Integer minutesAfterMidnight = null;
        DialogPreference preference = getPreference();
        if (preference instanceof TimePreference) {
            minutesAfterMidnight = ((TimePreference) preference).getTime();
        }

        // Set the time to the TimePicker
        if (minutesAfterMidnight != null) {
            int hours = minutesAfterMidnight / 60;
            int minutes = minutesAfterMidnight % 60;
            boolean is24hour = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getContext());

            mTimePicker.setIs24HourView(is24hour);
            mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hours);
            mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(minutes);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        if (positiveResult) {
            // Get the current values from the TimePicker
            int hours;
            int minutes;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                hours = mTimePicker.getHour();
                minutes = mTimePicker.getMinute();
            } else {
                hours = mTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
                minutes = mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
            }

            // Generate value to save
            int minutesAfterMidnight = (hours * 60) + minutes;

            // Save the value
            DialogPreference preference = getPreference();
            if (preference instanceof TimePreference) {
                TimePreference timePreference = ((TimePreference) preference);
                // This allows the client to ignore the user value.
                if (timePreference.callChangeListener(minutesAfterMidnight)) {
                    // Save the value
                    timePreference.setTime(minutesAfterMidnight);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### PreferenceFragmentCustom.java

```
public class PreferenceFragmentCustom extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
        // Load the Preferences from the XML file
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisplayPreferenceDialog(Preference preference) {

        // Try if the preference is one of our custom Preferences
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = null;
        if (preference instanceof TimePreference) {
            // Create a new instance of TimePreferenceDialogFragment with the key of the related
            // Preference
            dialogFragment = TimePreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.newInstance(preference.getKey());
        }


        if (dialogFragment != null) {
            // The dialog was created (it was one of our custom Preferences), show the dialog for it
            dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            dialogFragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "android.support.v7.preference" +
                    ".PreferenceFragment.DIALOG");
        } else {
            // Dialog creation could not be handled here. Try with the super method.
            super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference);
        }

    }
}
```

And the code in app_prefereces.xml for the Time picker :

```
        <de.jakobulbrich.preferences.TimePreference
            style="@style/AppPreference.DialogPreference"
            android:key="@string/pref_pref4"
            android:summary="@string/preferences_time_summ"
            android:title="@string/preferences_time_title"/>
```

So what is the best way to add a simple Date picker

Answer (score 0):

A simple way I use;

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.psinetron:slycalendarview:0.0.9'
}
```

**select picker button***

```
new SlyCalendarDialog()
        .setSingle(false)
        .setCallback(listener)
        .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG_SLYCALENDAR");
```

**interface implementation**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SlyCalendarDialog.Callback
```

When `onDataSelected`, you can do the same thing.

```
@Override
    public void onCancelled() {
        //Nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSelected(Calendar firstDate, Calendar secondDate, int hours, int minutes) {
        if (firstDate != null) {
            if (secondDate == null) {
                firstDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
                firstDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
                Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        new SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.timeFormat), Locale.getDefault()).format(firstDate.getTime()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG

                ).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        getString(
                                R.string.period,
                                new SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.dateFormat), Locale.getDefault()).format(firstDate.getTime()),
                                new SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.timeFormat), Locale.getDefault()).format(secondDate.getTime())
                        ),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG

                ).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Simple SharedPreferences save and get preferences;

```
private void savePreferences(context context, String date){
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
  mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
 mEditor = mPreferences.edit();

    mEditor.putString("save.date.pref", date);
    mEditor.commit();
}

private String getPreferences(Context context){
        private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
  mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
 mEditor = mPreferences.edit();

 mPreferences.getString("save.date.pref", "");
}
```

Comment: How to add it to the prefereces.xml

Comment: @AYMENSOUMER I don't understand what you want to do with it. Save date data in sharedPreferences?

Comment: yes , i want to use the date picker in preferences so i can save data easily

Comment: I've added a simple block of code where you can add it. @AYMENSOUMER

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my request is about Preferences Settings Screen

Comment: I would love to help, but I don't know about it.  I found this with a little research.  Look, if you want.
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.androidhive.info/2017/07/android-implementing-preferences-settings-screen/amp/

Have a nice day.